Is it possible to start a timer and select automatically a value in QField (Attribute form from QGIS)
I'm generating a form in QGIS 3.36 for QField and wonder if there is a way to select values in a list automatically based on the time since the first point in the 'site' column was added. Basically, I'd like my form to be able to select the time categories automatically (was the point taken in the first 5 minutes, between 5 and 10 minutes or between 10 and 15 minutes?).
This would be similar to apps such as eBird where it records the time from beginning to end of the list of species you record.

There could be a 'start' button to start a timer and add the points after that.
The column 'Heure_start' could be used to calculate how much time has passed since the start time to categories correctly.

Option 1 seems out of reach, but is it possible to do option 2?

